# jpa hibernate one-to-one update

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I'm working on an apartment management software and I'm having an issue.

There is two entities I have :

```
@Entity
public class Tenant extends AbstractEntity { //AbstractEntity contains the id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int number;
    @OneToOne
    private Apartment apartment;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Apartment extends AbstractEntity { //AbstractEntity contains the id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int number;
    @OneToOne
    private Tenant tenant;
}
```

But when I do

```
EntityManager em = emProvider.get();
em.getTransaction().begin();

em.merge(apartment);
em.flush();

em.getTransaction().commit();
```

It only save the Tenant into the Apartment but I would like it also update the Apartment into the Tenant.

Do I really need to set the apartment field into the tenant or there is a way to fix it simply?
Thanks

Cordially,
Baskwo

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Cascading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `CascadeType.ALL` in your Apartment entity. See sample

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Tenant tenant;
```

CascadeType.ALL is for all CRUD operation. Adjust CascadeType depends on your application needs.

Comment: I have one last question for you. It doesn't take effect immediately when I update the apartment so I need to restart the app.

Comment: it's depend on you application design. If you want to see latest updated   record in your UI, you can call SELECT method again and call em.refresh(yourobject)